# I get the Warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

I am confused as to why I get this warning[Warning] comparison between pointer and integer

```
while (fread(&searchrecord, sizeof(record), 1, fl) != NULL)
```

How I fix it?

Comment: don't compare a pointer with an integer

Comment: what type `fread()` returns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Please read e.g. [this `fread` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Comment: Don't compare an integer with a pointer, like the compiler tells you. [rtfm fread](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread).

Answer (score 5):

`fread` returns a `size_t` value which is an unsigned integral type. Your platform is defining `NULL` as `(void*)0` which is a pointer type.

Your compiler issues a warning since you're comparing these unrelated types.

The solution is to drop the `!= NULL` in your condition:

```
while (fread(&searchrecord,sizeof(record),1,fl))
```

which is clearer anyway.

Comment: The definition of `NULL` is implementation defined. `(void*)0` is just one widely used implementation. And C standard 6.3.2.3.3 (N1570) explicitly allow `NULL` ("null pointer constant") to be "an integer constant expression", so `NULL` is not necessarily of a pointer type.

Comment: @user3528438: Hum. Learn something new every day. I thought that was the C++ rule, and the C one was tighter. In response to your comment, I've loosened the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`fread` returns the number of items successfully read from the stream. You should compare that to the actual number you passed:

```
while (fread(&searchrecord, sizeof(record), 1, fl) == 1)
```

If you try and read more than one item, you should store the return value and compare that to `0`.